# django oraclepool uses only 2 sessions , WHY?

Tags: django, performance, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I'm using django 1.2.1 + cx_Oracle 5.0.4 11g + django oraclepool 0.7 + oracle client 11.2 under apache+mod_wsgi

in django oraclepool settings I set min:4 max:16 increment:1
when application started I see 4 sessions from httpd.exe
when i'm starting performace (64 concurrent threads) test only 2 sessions are active, and 2 inactive (if I set min:8, 2 active, 6 inactive),

WHY? what and how I need to configure to start using djangopool more than 2 sessions

UPD: server is dualcore, OS: windows server 2008r2

Comment: Hi andrew, I have this question in favorites. Have you found a solution for your issue? Can you share with us?

Comment: test tool, witch was written in .Net, was confugured to use 2 connections, I used http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html to understand how many Apache connections in use

Answer (score 1):

Just because you simulate 64 users doesn't mean that Django is handling a request from ever user at the same time. If requests are short in duration they simply may not overlap in time so as to require many concurrent threads and thus database sessions be used.

How this all behaves may also be dictated by the Apache MPM you are using and whether you are using mod_wsgi in embedded mode or daemon mode and what processes/threads is set for Apache and mod_wsgi daemon mode. So, you would need to provide more information about that.

Comment: thx, that you remember me to check mpm, but we have long sql queries (4 secs, 100k+ records), I enabled mpm, result is same

Comment: I found that testing tool works in 2 connection, so problem was in client test tool